# Android execute after a view is complete

Tags: java, android

I am new to this, so go easy on me.
I am trying to execute a piece of code that needs to know the new width and height of an ImageView after the device is rotated.

The following code catches the configuration change, but the ImageView hasn't actually been changed yet, so I cannot get an accurate height and width.

```
// This fires whenever the configuration of the device changes (Portrait to Landscape of vice versa)
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

// This procedure moves the items based on the new size of the ImageView.
   this.ShowMeasurements();
}
```

I have searched and looked at a number of ways that should work, but I am coming up short.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: try to use imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)

Comment: Yurii's answer below is generally the right way to "wait" for a view to be laid out before running code, but I'm curious why you think the ImageView will change sizes. Is it `match_parent` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure, that view has an accurate sizes you can try this code in `onCreate()`:

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int viewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
            if (viewWidth > 0 && viewHeight > 0) {
                //do some stuff here
            }
            //we remove this listener to not being notified every time the view
            //changes it's size. 
            //But if you need this info every time, just remove the last line
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

where, `imageView` is a reference to your `ImageView`